# TCPDF Rotate and Clip using a Rect Polygon inside the same transformation

Tags: tcpdf

So I'm using TCPDF in order to do some image manipulation on a PDF output.

What I have is an image (which needs to be rotated) and a clipping mask based on a Rect Polygon.

The problem I am facing is that when I do the transformation to rotate the image, the Rect Polygon I am using to do the clipping is also rotating.

Is there a way to rotate the image and then do the clipping after the initial StopTransform on the rotation has been executed?

Here's some sample code:

```
PDF::setXY($x, $y);
PDF::StartTransform();
PDF::Rotate($objectImageRotation * -1);
PDF::Rect($rectx, $recty, $rectwidth, $rectheight, 'CNZ');
PDF::Image($objectImageSrc, $x, $y, $width, $height, '', '', '', true, 300, '', false, false, ($objectBorderWidth > 0 ? 1 : 0), false, false, false);
PDF::StopTransform();
```

Now in the above, $rectx, $recty, $rectwidth and $rectheight are exactly where I want them to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much experimentation I figured out that by posting the 'Rect' before doing the actual rotation was the key to my requirement.

So given the above, the following change worked for me:

```
    ' Translate to a new XY coordinate in preparation for the placement of the image
PDF::setXY($x, $y);

    ' Start the transformation including the clipping according to the given shape and then rotating as per the rotation parameter
PDF::StartTransform();

    ' Clipping Rectangle
PDF::Rect($rectx, $recty, $rectwidth, $rectheight, 'CNZ');

    ' Rotate
PDF::Rotate($objectImageRotation * -1);

    ' Place the image at the set rotation
PDF::Image($objectImageSrc, $x, $y, $width, $height, '', '', '', true, 300, '', false, false, ($objectBorderWidth > 0 ? 1 : 0), false, false, false);

    ' Stop the transformation (reset)
PDF::StopTransform();
```